# Javascript extracting month, day and year formatting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following code that is suppose to extract day,month and year part separately.

```
  $scope.$watch('inlineDatepicker.date', function() {
       alert('hey, myVar has changed!' +$scope.inlineDatepicker.date);
       alert($scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getDay());
         alert($scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getMonth());
          alert($scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getUTCFullYear());

   });
```

Problem with the code is I can extract year correctly but day and month do not extract correctly. I tried as well

```
    alert($scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getUTCDady());
     alert($scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getUTCMonth())
```

Still wrong day and month. 
Please let me know how I can change it to get correct month and day values. Thanks. Here is the plunker for it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8v75gsz8ODUrTfu8S0sh?p=preview

Comment: Month is correct but it is indexed from 0 to 11, so just add 1.

Comment: You are using the day of the week function which gives 0 to 6 values. From memory, I think you want `getDate` instead for the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get day of month, use `getUTCDate()`
Month is zero based, so 0 means January, 11 December
Sample

```
$scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getUTCDate(); //prints day of month
$scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getUTCMonth() + 1; //prints month, 0 based, so add 1
$scope.inlineDatepicker.date.getUTCFullYear(); //prints 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Get day returns the day of the week. Use getDate() to return the day of the month. If you do getMonth(), january is 0 and december is 11.

You can see the reference documents here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp